# Large task size for simplest program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run the simplest program with Spark

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object LargeTaskTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DataTest").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val dat = (1 to 10000000).toList
    val data = sc.parallelize(dat).cache()
    for(i <- 1 to 100){
      println(data.reduce(_ + _))
    }
  }   
}
```

I get the following error message, after each iteration :

> WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (9767
>   KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

Increasing the data size increases said task size. This suggests to me that the driver is shipping the "dat" object to all executors, but I can't for the life of me see why, as the only operation on my RDD is reduce, which basically has no closure. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please remove `.toList` at `val dat` definition. I think  the source trouble is serizlization of `dat` within closure sent to master

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you create the very large list locally first, the Spark `parallelize` method is trying to ship this list to the Spark workers as a single unit, as part of a task. Hence the warning message you receive. As an alternative, you could parallelize a much smaller list, then use `flatMap` to explode it into the larger list. this also has the benefit of creating the larger set of numbers in parallel. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object LargeTaskTest extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DataTest").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val dat = (0 to 99).toList
  val data = sc.parallelize(dat).cache().flatMap(i => (1 to 1000000).map(j => j * 100 + i))
  println(data.count()) //100000000
  println(data.reduce(_ + _))
  sc.stop()
}
```

EDIT:

Ultimately the local collection being parallelized has to be pushed to the executors. The `parallelize` method creates an instance of ParallelCollectionRDD:

```
def parallelize[T: ClassTag](
      seq: Seq[T],
      numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism): RDD[T] = withScope {
    assertNotStopped()
    new ParallelCollectionRDD[T](this, seq, numSlices, Map[Int, Seq[String]]())
  }
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L730

ParallelCollectionRDD creates a number of partitions equal to `numSlices`:

```
  override def getPartitions: Array[Partition] = {
    val slices = ParallelCollectionRDD.slice(data, numSlices).toArray
    slices.indices.map(i => new ParallelCollectionPartition(id, i, slices(i))).toArray
  }
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ParallelCollectionRDD.scala#L96

`numSlices` defaults to `sc.defaultParallelism` which on my machine is 4. So even when split, each partition contains a very large list which needs to be pushed to an executor.

`SparkContext.parallelize` contains the note `@note Parallelize acts lazily` and `ParallelCollectionRDD` contains the comment;

> // TODO: Right now, each split sends along its full data, even if
>   later down the RDD chain it gets   // cached. It might be worthwhile
>   to write the data to a file in the DFS and read it in the split   //
>   instead.

So it appears that the problem happens when you call reduce because this is the point that the partitions are sent to the executors, but the root cause is that you are calling parallelize on a very big list. Generating the large list within the executors is a better approach, IMHO.

Comment: That's not it. The same warning happens with each iteration, after parallelize. The reduce is causing the warning, not the parallelize.

Comment: Did you try my example? It produces no such warning either at parallelize or at reduce.

Comment: Because your dat object is probably below the task memory warning limit, but I'm betting it still is being shipped to the executors although it shouldn't

Comment: The //TODO comment explains it then. Parallelize is just so lazy it just ships it for every action. Thanks.

Comment: Increasing `numSlices ` in the call to `parallelize` got the task size down for me when reading from a single file.

Answer (score -2):

Reduce function sends all the data to one single node. When you run `sc.parallelize` the data is distributed by default to 100 partitions. To make use of the already distributed data use something like this:

```
data.map(el=> el%100 -> el).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

or you can do the reduce at partition level.

```
data.mapPartitions(p => Iterator(p.reduce(_ + _))).reduce(_ + _)
```

or just use `sum` :)

Comment: As we can see from [the source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1001) reduce function runs distributed job via `runJob` where single partition and merge steps are defined. So it barely *sends all the data to one single node*

Comment: Yes. you are right. reduce is perfectly parallelisable. when you run `sc.parallelize` the driver splits the data into partitions that will be sent to the nodes. What the driver is doing is making sure each processing stage happens at the right time (when the data is available). ONLY the last stage of that reduce function will be sent back to the driver, everything else happens at the node level.
Did you try to increase the number of partitions by providing a value to the default argument of `sc.parallelize`