# How to send a collection to spark nodes only once?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Consider the simple code from this previous question:
[Large task size for simplest program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892240/large-task-size-for-simplest-program)

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object LargeTaskTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DataTest").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val dat = (1 to 10000000).toArray
    val data = sc.parallelize(dat).cache()
    for(i <- 1 to 100){
      println(data.sum)
    }
  }   
}
```

I have essentially the same question: how to get rid of the "task of very large size warning" on each iteration?

The accepted solution suggests creating the data in parallel using a `flatMap`. While this is a great solution for an integer range, **what if my data is in fact a collection of objects (from elsewhere in my program) that I can't create in parallel?**

I understand if for the first action, the data needs to be shipped to all the nodes resulting in a large task size. **However, for subsequent actions, can't the already-copied data be reused?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you just have to make more partitions, e.g. `val data = sc.parallelize(dat,1000).cache()`. Like this, the warnings disappear

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Thanks for the response. Sure, the size of each task will be reduced. But won't it still be copying the data to the nodes each time I call `sum`?

Comment: I should point out: my goal is not to make the warnings go away, **my goal is to address the underlying cause**.

Comment: I didn't know RDD had a `sum()` function...

Comment: @cricket_007 Technically it doesn't; I believe there is an implicit conversion happening to a DoubleRDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution: don't use `sc.parallelize`.  This isn't implemented especially efficiently, because it's really for teaching / debugging, and some actual use cases like parallelizing file names (small) and reading the files in an RDD map closure.

In this case, you can drastically reduce the size of the task by not converting the `Range` (O(1) memory footprint) to an `Array` (O(N) memory footprint).  Just remove the `toArray` and you shouldn't get those warnings again.

Comment: Thanks, this is very good to know. So if I shouldn't use `sc.parallelize`, how do you suggest creating an RDD over a collection? Especially when it's a collection of objects (instead of integers in this simple example).

Comment: What's your use case?  Usually your distributed dataset is too large to fit in memory on one machine, so you'd get it from parquet, csv, etc.  If your data start in a Scala collection, you're not going to have much benefit from Spark.

Comment: Although my dataset fits in one machine, my map operation is very expensive. In slightly more detail, my collection is a million vectors (in the mathematical sense) that I would like to multiply by a matrix exponential i.e. `exp(A)*v`. I should gain benefit from massive parallelization, correct?

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted Tim's answer: don't use `sc.parallelize`. To support his claim, creating the RDD in the following manner fixes the data-copying issue.

```
val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("tmp")
(1 to 10000000).foreach(pw.println)
pw.close()
val data = sc.textFile("tmp").map(_.toDouble).persist()
```